# If condition or for loop in a webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I am using this webgrid in my view.

```
 <div class="grid">
 @{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.SearchResults, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 15);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
 @grid.GetHtml(
           htmlAttributes: new { @style = "width:100%", cellspacing = "0" },
           columns: grid.Columns(
           grid.Column(header: "Customer Name", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.FullName, "ShowContracts", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @style = "color: 'black'", @onmouseover = "this.style.color='green'", @onmouseout = "this.style.color='black'" })),
           grid.Column(header: "SSN", format: item => item.SSN)
))
}
</div>
```

I search with SSN and display the results in a webgrid. The displayed data is dummy data. 
I have a bool AccountVerified in my viewmodel, now I should not give action link to the accounts which are not verified and display text next to them saying account verification pending. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Customer Name", 
    format: (item) => 
        (bool)item.AccountVerified 
            ? Html.ActionLink(
                  (string)item.FullName, 
                  "ShowContracts", 
                  new { 
                      id = item.UserId 
                  }, 
                  new { 
                      style = "color: 'black'", 
                      onmouseover = "this.style.color='green'", 
                      onmouseout = "this.style.color='black'" 
                  }
              ) 
            : Html.Raw("pending")
)
```

or write a custom HTML helper to avoid this monstrosity and simply:

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Customer Name", 
    format: item => Html.PendingLink(item)
)
```